# Empty exception using powershell to add a masterpage

Tags: 2010, powershell, master-page

When i try to add a masterpage to a web application using the following code :

```
$MasterPage = "C:\test.master"
$MasterPageName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($masterpage);
$SpWebApp = Get-SpWebApplication $Url
$Spsite = $spWebApp.sites[0]
$web = $spSite.OpenWeb();

#Check if the page is already there. 
$MasterPagelist = ($web).Lists |? {$_.Title -eq "Galerie met basispagina's"}
$item = $MasterPagelist.items |? {$_.Name -eq $MasterPageName}
$BaseMasterItem = $MasterPagelist.items |? {$_.Name -eq $BaseMasterPageName}

if($item -ne $null)
{
    Delete-MasterPage $MasterPageName $spSite
}

$MasterPagelist.RootFolder.Files.Add($MasterPageName, [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($MasterPage)) | out-null;
```

i get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): ""
At line:1 char:37
+ $MasterPagelist.RootFolder.Files.Add <<<< ("test", $MasterPageBytes)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The weird thing is that the error does not actually contain any usefull information. On my development farm this code works just fine, on my production farm it does not.

Any ideas on what could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this error is being caused by Microsoft Forefront Security, when I go to Central admin -> Security -> Manage antivirus settings, and from there I turn of the virus scan on uploaded documents this error no longer occurs.